# Effect of diode over the output

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, diodes, oscillator, timer

This is not homework. I'm just trying to understand this effect over the output of the oscillator.

I've simulated this circuit in LTSpice. I was expecting \$V_M\$ to oscillate between \$12 V\$ and \$0 V\$, but on the simulation the minimum value for the output is a little above \$0V\$. It is due to the resistor \$R_3\$.

Why is \$R_3\$ producing this effect to the minimum value of \$V_M\$? Why doesn't it also manifest to the maximum value \$12 V\$? When I increase the resistance for \$R_3\$ the effect disappears (as I expected because it cuts the effect of the diode) but when I decrease it to \$100 \Omega\$, \$50 \Omega\$ it also decreases... why?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not specifically R3 that is causing the output voltage not to reach 0 volts; it's the current through R3 (and the LED) that is causing a volt drop across the output impedance of the NE555 when it is supposedly 0 volts.

This doesn't happen when the NE555 output is high because there's no load current and hence, no volt-drop.

Comment: It is not clear to me how the drop at the Diode influences the output. Why can't it be zero? Do you mind to explain further?

Comment: The load current (for example) might be 67 mA (through R3 and the diode). If the output is pulling down hard to 0 volts this current flows but, if that output has an internal impedance of 7.5 ohm, the 67 mA raises the perfect output from 0 volts to  about 0.5 volts above 0 volts.

Comment: I think I'm getting it now. With "load current" do you mean the intrinsic current that goes through that path whenever the circuit is ON?

Comment: Yes, the current through R3 and the LED diode @ludicrous